# Is there a way to Categorize my custom controls in the toolbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I have built a number of asp.net servercontrols into a class library, & I would like them to be grouped a certain way when the other members of my team reference my dll.  Is that possible?  How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/chetanc/archive/2006/01/19/515016.aspx) that discusses how to add controls to the Visual Studio 2005 toolbox - including creating tabs to group the controls.

I made a version of this that works in a Custom Action, if you want more details let me know.